# Allow reputed members of community to suggest edits in the help center

Tags: feature-request, site-faq, help-center

Allow high rep (up for debate what rep requirement could be, maybe 20k+) users to propose edits directly to site help centers which would be only approve-able by site mods.

Stack Exchange is about to see a major reworking of its closing system. During these changes, the idea of topicality is going to reign supreme. However, a handful of mods are going to be extremely hard-pressed to keep up with the "evolving" topicality. Not only will they be trying to keep up with all of the new custom messages users will create to close questions, and the flags and disputes that will cause, but they will then have to mold the help center to match the legitimate ones.

Allowing the community to help fill in the gap of maintaining what is considered on topic will help balance out the work of ensuring "on-topic" remains relevant. As it stands, the interface may have changed but the content feels stale ([for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Why? You can already propose any change you want on Meta, and that's not limited to higher rep users.

Comment: @Yannis - I looked at the faq-proposed tag and it did not seem to get much attention. Should there really be a few dozen meta propositions for edits in the help center? At present the help center does not really reflect the changes being made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What we're seeing right now is a flurry of changes as a result of new systems being deployed, but it is certainly not going to be the case in the long term and developing a whole new system seems wasteful.

More importantly though, any changes to the help center should be vetted by the community as a whole, not by a couple folks who happen to check suggested edits. Posting on meta is the right way to go about doing that.

I expect that most of these articles will not need to be edited all that frequently, if at all. In other words, this is no different than the current system of users proposing changes to the FAQ, the community weighing in on the wording and deciding whether the changes are needed at all, and the moderators "making it so".

Comment: I can see your point about the long term issue with regards to this being sort of an anomaly. I guess the flurry just made me try to think of streamlining.